# How to add this jQuery script to coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript and not sure how to add this code to it. How do I write it in coffeescript language?

```
$(function() {
    YesClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

So far I have this but not compiling as same code:

```
  $ ->
    do YesClick = ->
      YesClick.attach(document.body)
  return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I had no idea what `do` was, but it turns out it is actually a thing, for anyone who doesn't know this. http://rzrsharp.net/2011/06/27/what-does-coffeescripts-do-do.html

Anyway, it's not necessary here, and the JS:

```
$(function() {
    YesClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

Can be written as:

```
$ -> 
  YesClick.attach(document.body)
```